# Little mysql_queries takes too much time

Tags: php, mysql, optimization

I have couple very small sql queries that takes too much time to run.

```
if ($USER) {
$ss_a = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT uri FROM styles WHERE     id=".$USER["styles"]));

if ($ss_a) {
$ss_uri = $ss_a["uri"];
}
}
```

So it takes  0.7605552s "SELECT uri FROM styles WHERE id=1"

And second style code

```
if (!$ss_uri) {
($r = mysql_query("SELECT uri FROM styles WHERE id=1")) or die(mysql_error());
```

Other little queries that takes too much time.

0.5507469  SELECT COUNT(id) AS problems FROM helpdesk WHERE solved = 'no'

Code:

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(id) AS problems FROM helpdesk WHERE solved = 'no'");

$arr     = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
$problems = $arr['problems'];
```

Is there any way to optimizing these or something?

Comment: Is your table big? If yes: how big? Is 'id' an index? If not, why not? :)

Comment: Can you provide more info? Mysql version, OS, tables size.

Comment: see [**this**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13944956/the-mysql-extension-is-deprecated-and-will-be-removed-in-the-future-use-mysqli).... `mysql_*` is deprecated (officially in php 5.5)

Answer (score 0):

Indexes might help.  I would suggest trying:

```
create index idx_styles_id_uri on style(id, uri)
create index idx_helpdesk_solved_id on helpdesk(solved, id)
```